# Can we ignore air resistance?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, projectile, drag, approximations

Is there any case in **real** life we can get the **right** (correct) "equations of motion" for object with  ignoring air resistance? In any object condition (size or shape of the object we are studying).

Comment: “Right” to what degree?

Comment: Exactly right 

Comment: "Exactly right" is meaningless (but an explanation of why it's meaningless would involve quantum mechanics, which you probably haven't studied yet). The only practical definition of "right" is "close enough to what happens the real world to be useful".

Comment: Even the classical equations of motion don't give the "exactly right" answer. In real life you will always have to account for air resistance because it is always there assuming you are somewhere on Earth.

Comment: You can only ignore it when there is no air. For example, in vacuum.

Comment: Why pick air resistance as the destroyer of "exactly right?" Even in classical mechanics on Earth there are the rotation of the Earth, the non-uniform density of Earth, changing altitudes, etc.

Comment: Relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0412107

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot ignore it if you want to get exactly right.  In fact, you need precise measurements of every single atom in the system in order to be exactly right.  And even then, quantum mechanics says you will only be statistically right.

We do not attempt to get exactly right.  We don't even try.  What we try to do is get right enough that the predictions we make are meaningful.

In many situations, the predictions you make ignoring air resistance are highly meaningful.  They are useful to such a degree that we don't even teach real air resistance until several years into someone's physics career.

Answer (score 0):

A pendulum is a practical example when it is easy to test the accuracy of ignoring air resistance.

If you measure the period of oscillation $T = 2 \pi \sqrt {\frac{L}{g}}$ with a chronometer, the measurement error will be probable bigger than the combined effect of air resistance and the approximation of small angle used for the formula.

Not surprisingly they were used so long to measure time.

Answer (score 0):

The [Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number) characterizes how important viscous forces are relative to inertial forces.

At higher Reynolds numbers, the viscous losses are small.  At lower Reynolds numbers, the viscous losses affect the motion more.

It's defined as

$$Re = {\rm{inertial forces} \over {\rm{viscous forces}}} = {{\rho u L}\over{\mu}} = {{u L}\over \nu} $$

where $\mu$ is the dynamic viscosity and $\nu$ is the kinematic viscosity, $u$ is the flow speed and $L$ is a typical dimension.

So the answer to the question is:  When the speed and size are large compared to the viscosity, you can ignore the air resistance.

For air, the kinematic viscosity is roughly $15 \times 10^{-6} m^2/s$ so if the product of size and speed is very large compared to that, the air resistance is small.